# how to get the full blob path from CloudBlockBlob

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

**Is it possible to get the full path of a CloudBlockBlob?**

I have an output binding to a `CloudBlockBlob`:

```
[Blob("%Detach:OutputContainer%/{file}", FileAccess.Write)] CloudBlockBlob @out
```

Here's how I am writing to this output:

```
await @out.UploadTextAsync("some string");
```

**How do we get the full blob path of this CloudBlockBlob without having to parse `%Detach:OutputContainer%/{file}`?**

The reason I am asking is because when my function has completed, I'd like to automatically add a queue message with this binding:

`[Queue("%Detach:DoneQueue%")] ICollector<Done> q,`

I am doing something like: `q.Add(@out.HowDoWeGetThisBlobPath())` ?

Comment: By "path", do you mean just the URi for the blob? You can get that via CloudBlob.Uri. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.uri?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: what ever is available so that i can identify the name and the container that it is in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name, Container, and URI are all already identified on the Blob instance when it's passed into the ctor. The call to Upload() is just writing the contents.

So you should be able to do:

```
q.Add(@out.Uri);
```

More on CloudBlob properties:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.uri?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: This is correct. Just note, whatever your `Done` object is, put that into your queue, not just the string/URI.